# Xtext: Grammar multiple option

Tags: xtext

This examples grammar does not compile due to multiple option in Exp

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals   

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    (a+=ContrSpec)+
    (c+=Exp)+
;

ConstrName:
    name=ID
;

ContrSpec:
    'const' name=ConstrName ('('')')?
;

Exp:
    c=[ConstrName]|
    i=ID
;
```

the grammar diagram looks like

```
       ID
     /    \
Exp--      --
     \    /
       ID
```

it can be solved by

```
 Exp:
    ->c=[ConstrName]|
    i=ID
;
```

but the syntax diagram stay the same.

- Does a different method exist to solve the problem?
- Can the multiple `ID` in the syntax diagram result in problem later?

**Update 1:**
This at least solve the parsing case

```
Model:
    (a+=ContrSpec)+
    (b+=VarSpec)+
    (c+=Exp)+
;

Name:
    VarName | ConstrName
;

VarName:
    name=ID
;

ConstrName:
    name=ID
;

VarSpec:
    'var' name=VarName
;

ContrSpec:
    'const' name=ConstrName ('('')')?
;

Exp:
    el=[Name] ('()')? |
    is_int?='Int'
;
```

Comment: Lexing is done before parsing so having two something=ID will never be distinguishable

Comment: Using Exp: `c=[ContrSpec] | i=ID;` give the same problem. How can the grammar be given so it can distinguish between the ID and element of type ConstrName or ContrSpec?

Comment: There is no possibility on grammar level xxx=[Yyy] is short for xxx=[Yyy|ID] which means it will be parsed as xxx=ID.

Comment: So what should be the criteria for picking a or b? The only way to ge this done is to customize linking. Have never done this myself

Comment: Later I want to add an optional '()' to follow [ConstrName]  `c=[ConstrName] ('()')?`. The brackets '()' must never appear after `i=ID`.

Comment: Well optional is the same as not there at all. So what is the criteria to distinguish the 2

Comment: Just the type of the element, but the lexer does not make the distinction. Changed to `Exp: ID ('()')?` and it works. I will make sure that the '()' only matches `ConstrName` in the validation code.

Comment: Then you have to dive into custom linking etc

Comment: Ps even the parser cannot distinguish

Comment: @Christian I updated the the question. The validation code I referred to are automatic generated `class MyDslValidator extends AbstractMyDslValidator ` etc. What is the custom linking you referred to?

Comment: Christian is referring to org.eclipse.xtext.linking.ILinkingService, which handles resolving cross-references at a lower level than Scope Providers, but this is something that you don't have to touch under normal circumstances, and I'd definitely not recommend it for this kind of problem. As you already resolved your problem by changing the grammar in a way that fits better into Xtext (and parsing in general), I suppose it's better to stick with that solution.